# Как отдать файл на скачивание но при этом подменить имя скачиваемого файла?

Tags: php, jquery

Как этот код написать на JQuery или сделать это на php

```
<a href="http://mysite.ru/upload/556544.doc" download="10 тестовый файл.doc">10 тестовый файл</a>
```

Если на такую ссылку кликнуть то файл `556544.doc` скачаеться как `10 тестовый файл.doc` все супер, как это повторить на JQuery или на php?

**UPD**

Сейчас на php сделал так.

```html
if(isset($_GET["file"])) {
    
    
    $fileid = $_GET["file"];
    

    $sql_downloadfile = "SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE `id`=".$fileid;
    $result_downloadfile = mysqli_query($db,$sql_downloadfile) or die("Ошибка: " . mysqli_error($db));

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result_downloadfile) > 0) {

    $file = mysqli_fetch_array($result_downloadfile);
    $filelink = "http://mysite.ru/panel/files/".$file["localfile_title"];


    // заставляем браузер показать окно сохранения файла
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($filelink));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    // читаем файл и отправляем его пользователю
    readfile($filelink);


    } else {

    echo 'ФАЙЛ НЕ НАЙДЕН!';

    }

}
```

Как изменить имя для качаемого файла?

Вопрос рише

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$new_file_name.'"');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один из вариантов - сохраните этот код в php файл. После его запуска будет скачан файл, ссылка на который прописана в `download_file()`:

```
<?php

download_file('https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhQIG.jpg', 'Картинка.jpg');

function download_file($file, $name) {
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $name);
    exit(readfile($file));
}
```

Comment: Так и сделал, но как имя качаемого файла подменить на свое?

Comment: @Анатолий подправил свой ответ.